# Programmatically onboard a Spotify Connect device to my account

Tags: spotify, mdns

Spotify Connect supports onboarding a device (i.e. wifi speaker) into your account directly from your Spotify Application. This is done through a protocol called informally zeroconf. It has been [reversed engineered](https://github.com/librespot-org/librespot/wiki/Authentication) and documented to some extend.

Sadly, all the documentation on the internet explains how to implement your own Spotify Connect device.

I'm searching for the other side: How can I onboard a Spotify Connect device into my account. I have an OAuth2 Token.

I already gathered some information

- The Spotify Connect Device announces an HTTP endpoint via MDNS
- On this http endpoint, you do a POST to the announced endpoint, providing `action=addUser` and various more parameters as form encoded payload:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME="theomega86"
TOKEN="BQBfYx[REDACTED]kMqbtlg"
curl -v -X POST -d "action=addUser&userName=$USERNAME&tokenType=accesstoken&blob=$TOKEN&clientKey=&loginId=x&deviceName=x&deviceId=x&version=2.7.1" http://192.168.1.102:51368/0
```

I was able to retrieve the appropriate values by capturing the packages the Spotify client is sending to the Spotify connect device. The only interesting payload in this request is the `blob` parameter. While this is a good step forward, the provided blob runs out after one hour. Sadly this blob is not a normal OAUTH2 token (I tried providing that). Does anyone have an idea how to construct the `blob` payload, assuming that I have an oauth2 token ready?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I need a similar solution for my home automation project

Comment: The "blob" payload is documented here too: https://github.com/librespot-org/librespot/blob/master/docs/authentication.md#zeroconf-based-authentication

Comment: it looks like the HutSpot project may have some clues:  https://github.com/sailfish-spotify/hutspot/blob/master/src/connect/spconnect.cpp